# Error while executing apk project in ionic 2

Tags: android, mobile, ionic2, ngcordova

can you help me?

Hello, I am a ionic beginner and am trying to maintain an existing project in the company.

I configured the environment following the recommendations of the project developer with:

Java jdk, sdk manager, NodeJS, Ionic, ngcordova, git and bower

Can I open the project and run it through the start ionic service --lab

Need to make the modifications on two screens and that was fine.

To build the build I execute the following steps:

Add android platform

Ionic android construction

However, when installing a build.apk on a smartphone, the following error appears:

"Ionic failed to load resource: net :: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file: //android_asset/www.cordova.plugins.js"

And no feature works, other than browsing.

```html
 <!-- Dependencies -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-input-masks/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngMask/dist/ngMask.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-md5/angular-md5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-filter-bar/dist/ionic.filter.bar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/moment/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-close-popup/ionic-close-popup.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og03v.png)

Comment: If your app requires plugins you should install them using "ionic plugin add 'plugin-name'". Installed plugins are listed using "ionic plugin list"

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you very much for the response.

In the documentation of the app the only required plugin would be the ngcordova that I have already installed.

I changed the post inslucindo as dependents in index.html.

List of ionic plugins

Cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "device"

Comment: This is not an Ionic 2 project, I believe.

Comment: Hi Karuban, thank you very much for the response.How do I know?